# Joomla Email Not working

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, emails, user-registration

I am working on Joomla3.4. Joomla default registration page is created on menu. When i register activation email is not working. 
I uploaded simple email script which is working fine. Please help me with settings of joomla or something else so that email will work...
In Joomla configuation setting is "Mailer" as "sendMail".
I tried with PHP mail as well but both are not working.

Comment: What are your current settings? Are you working on localhost? Did it ever work?

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all? If not, set error reporting in your Global Configuration to `development`

Comment: Nopes I am working on my development server. I am not getting any error

Comment: So it has never worked? Can you message/email users from admin area? Anything in your server log files? Email configs can be difficult to troubleshoot as there are many potential causes. Show your current settings, blank out any passwords etc obviously...

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much always use the cmandrill plugin (https://compojoom.com/joomla-extensions/mandrill-transactional-emails-made-easy). It uses Mandrill (which is the engine behind MailChimp) to send out emails for you.
It avoids the need to figure out your server's email settings, and provides great reporting on what emails have been sent and whether they have been received / opened etc.
The Mandrill account is free up to a fairly large number of emails per month.